# How to make menus in a storyboard in xcode with cocoa and c#

Tags: c#, xcode, macos, visual-studio, xamarin

I want to make many menus like antiviruses do. I want it so when you click one of the many buttons I have on the left, all the other buttons will disable and this one wil stay enabled. And it will also hide and unhide certain elements in the storyboard. I am using visual studio but xcode for the storyboard.[image: Image of what it will look like]

This is how it may look like. and then to the left it will display the elements I want.

Answer (score 1):

We can implement this in code , just place a series of Buttons and remove the other buttons when clicking on specific one .

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            List<NSButton> array = new List<NSButton>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                NSButton button = new NSButton();
                button.Frame = new CGRect(5, 40 * i + 10, 100, 30);
                button.Title = i.ToString();
                button.Font = NSFont.SystemFontOfSize(20);
                this.View.AddSubview(button);
                array.Add(button);

                button.Activated += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    foreach(var b in array)
                    {
                        if(b != button)
                        {
                            b.RemoveFromSuperview();
                        }
                    }
                };               
            }
        }
```